# Is soil in an open rock spoon drain a blocker? Think we've got a cowboy job done

Tags: plumbing, drain, drainage

Being on a slope, our place has a lot of problems with surface water flooding. We've had a spoon drain installed along our upper boundary to redirect surface water away from the house.

Here's a pic of the spoon drain, it's supposed to be 300mm deep and 1.5m wide, with large rocks packed into the sides to give a U shape. Doesn't look like that description, theres so much soil in there I think it's probably blocked before we even get rain.

[image]

Is this an issue? Or will the rain wash it out?